# Gimp: how to create a realistic tumbler mockup

Tags: print-design, gimp, print-production

I'm buying a bunch of [RTIC-Tumbler-30-oz](https://www.rticcoolers.com/shop/drinkware/tumblers/RTIC-Tumbler-30-oz) to get engraved for my family.

However I was hoping to do a "full body" engraving and wanted to do mock ups of the engraving.  But with the middle having a very steep and sudden decline and the overall decline of a cup (from top to bottom), its not a simple calculation.

Does anyone know how I can calculate the layout so I can create mockups in GIMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy answer: The vendor should supply you with a template.

Harder answer: You need a sample of the tumbler, to measure its exact radii at top & bottom of the imprint area (which you will have to ask your vendor about; and don't be surprised if the vendor is clueless, happens all the time), and then use this tutorial to calculate your imprint area: http://tuckyhut.com/curved-dielines-and-warping-tutorial-part-2-create-dieline-for-cup-package/